# Issue with depcache-py3.5.json in pip-tools for python 3

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

On running the below command

```
pipenv install <software> --python 3.5
```

I get the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/somansh/.cache/pip-tools/depcache-py3.5.json'
```

I checked my /home/somansh/.cache/pip-tools/ folder which only has depcache-py2.7.json

How do I install the required version for 3.5

Comment: `ls -l /home/somansh/.cache/pip-tools`?

Answer (score 1):

This might have nothing to do with Python or *pip*. Check the rights and owners on your files and directories.